# Mule JDBC dynamic IN clause data mismatch

Tags: mule

I'm trying to update one column for multiple records using IN for the clause and a jdbc outbound.

```
update someTable set aColumn = myvalue where bColumn in(id_1, id_2)
```

I'm setting a variable, which brings back the id's (numbers) I'm looking for, but when trying to replace the numbers into the update statement it's complaining about a datatype mismatch. I've tried both of these set-variables with no success. (The jdbc outbound is below it)

```
<set-variable variableName="numbers" value="#[message.payload.numbers;int]" 
    doc:name="set numbers var" />

<set-variable variableName="numbers" value="#[message.payload.someNumbers]" 
   doc:name="set numbers var" />

<jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryTimeout="-1" 
    doc:name="update timestamp" 
    connector-ref="AS400" queryKey="updateCellTblTimestamp">
   <jdbc:query key="updateCellTblTimestamp" 
      value="update mytbl set mycolumn = somevalue where myid in(#[flowVars.numbers]) "/>
</jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
```

using Mule 3.3.1 CE

Comment: I am struggling with this right now. Did you make any headway with it?

Comment: @Rondo  Yes, this is what I've done:    <outbound-endpoint      address="jdbc://update tblName set columnName = whatEverUwant          where anthongTblColumn in (#[flowVars.someIds])" 
    connector-ref="AS400" 
    doc:name="update something" 
    doc:description="update something"/>  hope this helps.

Comment: ...thanks for the response ... looks like what I have and I keep getting 'java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type' from oracle jdbc driver... my sql in clause is "...and e.event_id in (#[message.payload]).." .. the only param in the query. Debugging shows that the payload is an Object[] .... event_id is a Number ... stumped (edit: the Objects are all instanceof Integer)

Comment: .... and I transformed the payload to an int[] with no effect on the outcome

Comment: Yes, that makes sense that you're still getting sqlExceptions since what you are passing is an array of ints and that is not what the query is expecting. This is how I did it: in your transformer build your id list as a string so from your int[] build a string with comma separated values: "2,5,8" then set as a with:    <set-variable variableName="eventIds" value="#[message.payload.formattedIds]" doc:name="set id var"/>
Then pass this variable in your query as in the sample I gave above.

Comment: I tried what you hare suggesting and was unable to get the oracle jdbc driver to accept it as anything other than a typed parameter value, and hence it would fail since the ojdbc driver does not accept an array as a parameter to a where-clause nor will it allow you to construct DML, which is what the string list of ints is doing. Limiation of the jdbc driver (oracle) I moved on and split the collection into individual queries.  Thanks for responding